# Arrangement of the following term

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, exponential-sum, sums-of-squares

How

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{2m}}$$

can be rewritten as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2k-2}}{(2k-1)^{2m}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2k-1}}{(2k)^{2m}}$$

???

Comment: All the previous comments and answers are right but also don't forget to check the existence of all the sum you're considering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every positive integer $n$ is either even, i.e., of the form $n=2k$ for $k \geq 1$, or odd, i.e., of the form $n=2k-1$ for $k \geq 1$.

More formally, if $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{\text{odd } n=1}^\infty f(n)+\sum_{\text{even } n=1}^\infty f(n)$$ since addition of real numbers is commutative and hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{k = 1}^\infty f(2k-1)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(2k).$$

Comment: Why in the first summand, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2k-2}}{(2k-1)^{2m}}$, the power of numerator is $(2k-2)$ ? not $2k$?

Comment: Because $n=2k-1$ there, so $(-1)^{n-1}=(-1)^{(2k-1)-1}=(-1)^{2k-2}$.  [In any case, $(-1)^{2k-2}=(-1)^{2k}$.]